# Tableau Filter Formula

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to filter workgroup name that only contains BL or CL so I used the formula...

```
STARTSWITH([wrkgrp_shrt_nm], "BL") or STARTSWITH([wrkgrp_shrt_nm], "CL" )
```

I get the little green check, but when I hit apply it is blank and nothing pulls through

I tried another formula...

```
if right([wrkgrp_shrt_nm],2) = 'BL' then 1 elseif
right([wrkgrp_shrt_nm],2) = 'CL' then 1 elseif
right([wrkgrp_shrt_nm],2) then 0
end
```

but I am only getting an error

any suggestions?

Comment: I was able to make STARTSWITH([wrkgrp_shrt_nm], "BL") or STARTSWITH([wrkgrp_shrt_nm], "CL" ) work after a few more attempts, used it as a T/F filter and it did the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you want "contains", you can just call contains()

```
contains(wrkgrp_shrt_nm, 'BL') or contains(wrkgrp_shrt_nm, 'CL')
```

Does the same thing as the find() solution Fred posted, just a little easier to read in this case. I'm not sure why Fred says you cannot use `IF`. I use IF all the time without problems.

BTW, in case you were wondering, the square brackets around field names are optional if the field name does not include spaces or punctuation, and function names are not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you're asking for "contains BL or CL", but your formula specify STARTSWITH which will be true is your field [wrkgrp_shrt_nm] starts with the string "BL" or the string "CL".

If you want "contains", you could use FIND:

```
FIND([wrkgrp_shrt_nm], 'BL' ) > 0 OR FIND([wrkgrp_shrt_nm], 'CL' ) > 0
```

You cannot use `IF` in a condition field, but you can use inline IF (`IIF`), however it's not necessary in your case.

Edit:
I can totally be wrong with my comment on `IF` (because I'm still new in Tableau) but I tried `IF` in a condition field of a filter (as the OP asked) and I can't make it work. I use IF all the time in Calculated Fields however. I'll try again...